# How to create JWT token in arangodb by using foxx microservices?

Tags: javascript, arangodb, foxx, arangodb-foxx

I need to create JWT token for authentication (login) and expire it on logout. So what is the procedure for it ?

I am using foxx micro services to do database manipulation.
JWT token must be created by using service and token will be expire when user logout from website or token expire time completed.

Comment: please provide some sample code that you have tried.

Comment: i am currently using the default JWT token  /_open/auth api, but after looking into documentation i didn't find any method to expire a JWT token. So i need to know how can i expire a particular JWT token ?

Comment: I've had a look at this in the past and struggled validating the JWT token, because you don't get access to the crypto library in the Community Edition of ArangoDB.